# Convert edge list to adjacency matrix

Tags: matlab, adjacency-matrix

if i have the following code in matlab

```
function adj=edgeL2adj(el)
nodes=sort(unique([el(:,1) el(:,2)])); % get all nodes, sorted
adj=zeros(numel(nodes));   % initialize adjacency matrix
% across all edges
for i=1:size(el,1);adj(find(nodes==el(i,1)),find(nodes==el(i,2)))=el(i,3);
end
```

that convert edge list `m x 3` to adjacency list `n x n` but i have a matrix of edge list `m x 2` so what is the required change in previous code that give me true result.

example:

```
if edge list =[1 2;2 3;2 4] then adjacency matrix=[0 1 0 0;0 0 1 1;0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally do away with your loop code and take advantage of [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) then convert back to a [`full`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html) matrix if desired.  The first column consists of the source node and the second column consists of the target node.  You simply set all of these entries in the sparse matrix to 1.  However, judging from your code, the third column of your edge list is also the corresponding weight, and so I'll write code that will assume both cases.  Also, make sure you filter out duplicate rows using `unique`:

## Example with weights just being 1

```
edgelist = [1 2;2 3;2 4];
edgelist = unique(edgelist, 'rows');
sz = max(edgelist(:));
A = sparse(edgelist(:,1), edgelist(:,2), 1, sz, sz);
```

The first line of code denotes your edge list where each row pair consists of two nodes incident with each other (i.e. they are connected by an edge).  The second line removes any duplicate rows from the edge list.  The third line determines how big the adjacency matrix should be.  We need to figure out what the largest node ID is so that we can allocate a `N x N` sparse matrix where `N` is the largest node ID.  The last line of code simply uses the first column and second column of the edge list to populate the entries in the sparse matrix, we set them to one and ensure that the size of the matrix is `N x N`.

We get this:

```
>> A

A =

   (1,2)        1
   (2,3)        1
   (2,4)        1
```

You can optionally convert the matrix to full by using the `full` function:

```
>> full(A)

ans =

     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

As you can see, this corresponds with your desired result.

## Example with weights in the third column

```
edgelist = [1 2 0.1;2 3 0.2;2 4 0.3];
edgelist = unique(edgelist, 'rows');
sz = max(max(edgelist(:, 1:2)));
A = sparse(edgelist(:,1), edgelist(:,2), edgelist(:,3), sz, sz);
```

Same code as before, but you're changing the third parameter to `sparse` with the third column of `edgelist`.

This is what we get:

```
>> A

A =

   (1,2)       0.1000
   (2,3)       0.2000
   (2,4)       0.3000

>> full(A)

ans =

         0    0.1000         0         0
         0         0    0.2000    0.3000
         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: @ChisholmKyle has a comment for you under their answer.

Answer (score -1):

An adjacency matrix should only contain boolean values to indicate an edge is present between vertices. I think this function assumed the third column of `el` is all ones. In the comments it is clarified that perhaps they are in fact weights. The function can be simplified too. Here's the modified code:

```
function adj=edgeL2adj(el)
    nodes=unique(el(:, 1:2)); % get all nodes, sorted
    adj=zeros(numel(nodes));   % initialize adjacency matrix
    % across all edges
    for i=1:size(el,1)
        adj(nodes==el(i,1),(nodes==el(i,2)))=1;
        % if third column is weights, 
        % adj(nodes==el(i,1),(nodes==el(i,2)))=el(i, 3);
    end
```

Comment: Adjacency matrices frequently use the value to indicate edge weight; the third column of `el` in the original problem would not have necessarily been all ones.

Comment: Ah good to know. I'm not too familiar with graphs, vertices and adjacency matrices. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment on other answers, but @raryeng if you see this, the original function calls `unique()` so it is intended to ignore repeated vertices. Perhaps you can modify your code to maintain the same functionality as the function in question?

Comment: Repeated edges between two vertices won't have an effect as the entry in the sparse matrix simply gets replaced with a 1. However you can apply unique over the rows if so desired. With that, I'll edit my post soon.

Comment: A weird thing happens with repeated values. Looking into the documentation for [sparse](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html), buried deep below is this line: **If i and j have identical values for several elements in v, then those elements are added together** so it won't just be a `1`, but the number of duplicates.

Comment: Interesting. It must have changed with later versions. On mine it replaces the values. Thanks for the tip.